# How to set requireNativePath for require.js in Play app

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, requirejs

The Play Framework version 2.1.0 docs state:

> by default a rhino based optimizer is used, the native, node version can be configured for performance via requireNativePath setting

but there's no example of how/where to actually do this.  When I deploy my app to Heroku the optimization step is taking upwards of 10 minutes and causes the build to fail fairly regularly.  Can anyone point me to how I should be setting this requireNativePath flag?

Comment: hey @rphutchinson, take a look at my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/20694646/2141561 to get heroku to optimize way faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the project settings:

```
requireNativePath := Some("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js")
```

You can also check out this sample app: https://github.com/magro/play2-java-computer-database/tree/master/play-coda

Comment: This dramatically reduced our RequireJS optimization time. Thanks Martin. Also, the example project you set up to demonstrate the configuration is great as it leaves no ambiguity. Thanks, great answer!

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to get `requireNativePath` to work on Heroku as you will have to fork and modify the scala buildpack to get improvements. though, by following the steps below you will speed up optimization by more than 10X (It was taking me ~700+ seconds to deploy, now it only takes ~65 seconds)

Go ahead and fork the scala buildpack and apply the [modifications from here](https://github.com/Hylozoic/heroku-buildpack-scala/compare/beforeRequireJs...addRequireJS).  These modifications essentially install node and npm, then install requireJS node_module.

After you add the modifications to your buildpack, you have to tell heroku to use your custom buildpack via the CLI

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/<your user>/heroku-buildpack-scala
```

Next, modify your `Build.scala` project settings by adding this line

```
requireNativePath := scala.util.Properties.envOrNone("REQUIREJS_PATH")
```

Next set a config variable on heroku for the `REQUIREJS_PATH` via CLI.  This is the path that the buildpack modifications will install the r.js file:

```
$ heroku config:set REQUIREJS_PATH=/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/vendor/node/bin/r.js
```

Next you have to enable the `user-env-compile` lab from heroku.  This will let you access any environment variables from the compilation process.

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

After you complete the above steps, you can now push your latest changes to heroku and you will notice that the optimization step takes 10x less time

Comment: Hi Ray,
I get the following error when I try to build. I forked your scala build pack. The heroku configs also gave no errors. Any ideas?

[info] RequireJS optimization has begun...

[info] app.build.js:
[info] ({appDir: "javascripts",
[info]           baseUrl: ".",
[info]           dir:"javascripts-min", modules: [{name: "app"}]})
[error] RequireJS optimization has failed...
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Users/baku/AppData/Local/Temp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/vendor/node/bin/r.js": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: it looks like you set the REQUIREJS_PATH config variable wrong on heroku.  It needs to be set to: /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/vendor/node/bin/r.js but it looks like you have it as: C:/Users/baku/AppData/Local/Temp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/vendor/node/bin/r.js‌​

Comment: Aah maybe just too late in the night :)

Comment: After **Feb 27, 2014** npm stopped allowing selfed signed certs (http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more)  I updated the buildpack to inlcude a fix to this issue: https://github.com/Hylozoic/heroku-buildpack-scala-with-requirejs/compare/beforeRequireJs...addRequireJS